# npm states modules are missing that aren't

Tags: npm

Below is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "web_app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Brad",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-file-include": "^0.13.7",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-size": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.1.0",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.6",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs-es": "^5.0.0-beta.9"
  }
}
```

When in run 'npm install' I get the following errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.3.1 should be installed with -g
```

As I don't have modules like 'minimatch' in my package.json file I'm assuming that other modules depend on it. So I installed all the outdated modules globally. This didn't remove the error messages. If I try and run say a gulp task it will work, however, if I restart my computer and then try and run the same gulp task, it will say modules are missing, even though they are in the node_modules folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your dependencies are using deprecated packages.

Try running *npm ls*  to find which dependencies are referencing old packages.

[image]

Comment: that does list everything but how are you supposed to update those packages? running 'npm outdated' doesn't return anything and running 'npm update' doesn't update them

Comment: Correct. npm outdated will only show the outdated packages you have listed as dependencies, its up to the publishers of the package to update the deprecated ones, so you can either use a different package, or ignore the warnings (not critical) if they don't represent an issue or security flaw.

Comment: Well if that isn't the issue, does anyone know why I need to reinstall all modules each time I restart my comp.

Answer (score 0):

Update minimatch to latest version 3.0.2 by running following command

```
npm update -g minimatch@3.0.2
```

Comment: For me, it worked after downgrading my Node.js version